# Free geophysical software with GUI

Tags: geophysics, software

I'm looking for free software for marine surveying, such as [Madagascar](http://www.ahay.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [Seismic Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_Unix), but preferably with a graphical user interface

Comment: What have you found so far?  Ideally list what you have tried and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: This might be more suited to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/